# How to show different categories in different pages?

Tags: posts, categories

I have this webpage with blog and a page with latest news. Right now both pages are showing the same category. How do I separate them? so that one page show category 1 and the other show category 2?

code for category_blog.php

```
<!--<tm_category>-->

<!--<div if else tm_category>-->
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'category-sidebar-widget-left' ) && is_active_sidebar( 'category-sidebar-widget-right' ) ) { ?>
<div class="tm_category_2">

<?php } elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'category-sidebar-widget-left' ) ) { ?>
<div class="tm_category_1">

<?php } elseif ( is_active_sidebar( 'category-sidebar-widget-right' ) ) { ?>
<div class="tm_category_1_right">

<?php } else { ?>
<div class="tm_category_0">

<?php } ?>
<!--</div if else tm middle post>-->

    <!--<category name>-->
    <div class="tm_cat_metatitle">
        <h1>
            <i class="icon-reorder"></i> 
            <?php echo single_cat_title( '', false ); ?> 
        </h1> 
        <div class="tm_cat_arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <!--</category name>-->

    <!--<tm_category_file>-->
    <div class="tm_category_file">
        <div class="tm_category_box">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <!--<the loop>-->
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <!--<cat title>-->
                <div class="tm_catpost_titles">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <h1 class="tmpost-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                            <?php $tit = the_title('','',FALSE); echo substr($tit, 0, 150); if (strlen($tit) > 150) echo " ..."; ?>
                            </h1>
                        </a>
                </div>
                <!--</cat title>-->     

                <!--<cat item>-->
                <div class="tm_cat_item">
                    <div class="tmpost-<?php the_ID(); ?>-item">

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_1">
                        <i class="icon-user"></i> 
                        <?php _e('By', 'tm_myid_text'); ?> <?php the_author(); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_2">
                        <i class="icon-tag"></i> 
                        <?php _e('In', 'tm_myid_text'); ?> <?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_3">
                        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                        <?php the_time('M jS, Y') ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_4">
                        <i class="icon-comments"></i> 
                        <?php comments_number(__('0 Comments', 'tm_myid_text'), __('1 Comment', 'tm_myid_text'), __( '% Comments', 'tm_myid_text') );?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_5">
                        <i class="icon-eye-open"></i> 
                        <?php echo tm_viewcounter_display(get_the_ID()); ?>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--</cat item>-->

                <!--<cat image>-->
                <div class="tm_cat_image">
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <!--</cat image>-->

                <div class="tm_cat_desc">
                    <div class="tmpost-desc">
                    <?php echo excerpt(300); ?> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="tm_cat_readmore">
                        <div class="tmpost-readmore">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                <i class="icon-file-text"></i> 
                                <?php _e('Read More', 'tm_myid_text'); ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="tmpost-readmore_list"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!--</the loop>-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--</tm_category_file>-->

    <!--<tm pagination>-->
    <div id="Nav">
        <div class="tm_navigation">
        <?php echo tm_pagination_nav(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--</tm pagination>-->

        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

</div>
<!--</tm_category>-->
```

this is the index code:

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: Home 5 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!--<home 5>-->

<!--<div tm_category 0>-->
<div class="tm_category_0">
<!--</div tm_middle 0>-->

    <!--<category name>-->
    <div class="tm_cat_metatitle">
        <h1>
            <i class="icon-reorder"></i> 
             Recent Posts           
        </h1> 
        <div class="tm_cat_arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <!--</category name>-->

    <!--<tm_category_file>-->
    <div class="tm_category_file">
        <div class="tm_category_box_home5">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <!--<the loop>-->
            <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                                                "cat" => "", 
                                                "posts_per_page" => "", 
                                                "post_type" => "post",
                                                "paged" => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
                                                )                                               
                                        );
            while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <!--<cat title>-->
                <div class="tm_catpost_titles">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <h1 class="tmpost-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                            <?php $tit = the_title('','',FALSE); echo substr($tit, 0, 150); if (strlen($tit) > 150) echo " ..."; ?>
                            </h1>
                        </a>
                </div>
                <!--</cat title>-->     

                <!--<cat item>-->
                <div class="tm_cat_item">
                    <div class="tmpost-<?php the_ID(); ?>-item">

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_1">
                        <i class="icon-user"></i> 
                        <?php _e('By', 'tm_myid_text'); ?> <?php the_author(); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_2">
                        <i class="icon-tag"></i> 
                        In <?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_3">
                        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                        <?php the_time('M jS, Y') ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_4">
                        <i class="icon-comments"></i> 
                        <?php comments_number(__('0 Comments', 'tm_myid_text'), __('1 Comment', 'tm_myid_text'), __( '% Comments', 'tm_myid_text') );?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_5">
                        <i class="icon-eye-open"></i> 
                        /*<?php echo tm_viewcounter_display(get_the_ID()); ?>/*
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--</cat item>-->

                <!--<cat image>-->
                <div class="tm_cat_image">
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'Full' ); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <!--</cat image>-->

                <div class="tm_cat_desc_home5">
                    <div class="tmpost-desc">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tm_cat_readmore">

                        <div class="tmpost-readmore">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                <i class="icon-file-text"></i> 
                                 <?php comments_number(__('(0) Kommentarer ', 'tm_myid_text'), __('(1) Kommentar', 'tm_myid_text'), __( '(%) Kommentarer', 'tm_myid_text') );?> 
                            </a>
                            <div class="tmpost-readmore_list"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!--</the loop>-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--</tm_category_file>-->

    <!--<tm pagination>-->
    <div id="Nav">
        <div class="tm_navigation">
        <?php echo tm_pagination_nav(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--</tm pagination>-->

        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<!--</home left>-->
<?php get_template_part( 'sidebar_left' ); ?>
<!--</home left>-->
<!--</home 5>-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Paste your code

Comment: from witch page? You want to see my index file or category.php or category_blog.php?

Comment: Which page do you want to show post of different categories?

Comment: Can you paste the code for blog page?

Comment: its in the question, was to long for comment

Comment: "its in the question, was to long for comment" You should always edit your question if you need to add code +1

Comment: How are these pages loaded? And why does your "index" code have a template name?

Comment: how do you mean loaded? My theme have 7 diffrent idex to use and Im using index 5 for these to pages because index 5 is the olny index that supports blog

Comment: Just for clarification: You want to show category index pages, but you do not want to use the standard WordPress urls for those?

Comment: I don't think i really follow? maby im really bad at saying what it is i need help with

Comment: You have posts on your site, sorted in 2 categories. You want one URL to display posts of category 1 in the design for category 1, another URL to display posts of actegory 2 in a different design?

Comment: almost correct! the design is gonna be same just they are gonna show diffrent post

Comment: "index 5" is not part of the WordPress template hierarchy. WordPress won't load that automatically. How do you have this organized? Are these all assigned to different "Pages"?

Comment: both pages are assigned with index 5 becausse thats the template i have to use.

Comment: Why don't you use the standard WordPress category template then (`category.php` in your theme directory)?

Comment: oh I dident think of that! but it dosent matter i solved it just gave another side anoter index.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `cat` to the category number you want. For example:

```
 "cat" => 2,
```

Or  if you know the category name you could also use:

```
"category" =>"category_name",
```

You should add any of the above two lines in your `wp_query` arguments like the one in below which is empty:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                                                    "cat" => "", 
                                                    "posts_per_page" => "", 
                                                    "post_type" => "post",
                                                    "paged" => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
                                                    )                                               
                                            );
```

Comment: but if I change that wont both pages show the same category then?

Comment: Change the `Wp_Query` of one of the page and it will show post of different category. For example change the `cat` for your `SENASTE NUMMRET` page and that page will show post of different category

Comment: I dont undertand. Bot pages are using the same index. How do I change on just one page?

Comment: Do you have access to code for SENASTE NUMMRET page?

Comment: SENASTE NUMMRET is using the same code as the other page BLOG. both pages are using the same code and index

Comment: I'm sorry then I'm  unable to help

Comment: both pages are using the same index but i still want them to show diffrent categorys. I now have to to do that if Im using 2 separated index but now its not possible

Comment: Hire someone to do that for you. It's a small task, so maybe a free lancer would do that easily

Comment: i solved it! just made a new index for the other page.

Comment: oh okay that's cool